# swift struct can't encode objectIdentifier

Tags: json, swift, core-data, encoding

Sorry for the messy formatting: tried to correct it, improved it a bit.

This is a struct that I'm trying to encode. It does conform to Codable now, but any inclusion of the rest of the content, always based on ObjectIdentifiers, blows up, so I conclude they present a problem for encoding.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to restore the entity relationships between a number of classes when I decode elsewhere. I don't see a way to get the JSON Encoder to see those relationships, so maybe there's a way to do that.

But in lieu I initialize the struct with the basic data. This is the simplest such struct, with only a name property in the class, but it also grabs the id of the project the Block belongs to, and attempts to initialize that value.

Afterwards, I loop through the different entities, and update the structs that are initialized with the Array values for comps, gitpaths, inProject, and selectionThreads.

So that's what I'm doing and the goal. The stumbling block is encoding the ObjectIdentifiers. What am I missing?

```
struct ProjectBlock : Codable {
/*
    var comps :             Array<ObjectIdentifier>?
    var gitpaths :          Array<ObjectIdentifier>?
    var inProject :         ObjectIdentifier?
    var selectionThreads :  Array<ObjectIdentifier>?
 */

    var name :              String
/*
    var exportObjID :       ObjectIdentifier
*/
init(block : Blocks) {
    name = block.name!
    /*
    exportObjID = block.id
    inProject = block.inProject!.id
     */
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    /*
    case comps =            "comps"
    case gitpaths =         "gitpaths"
    case inProject =        "inProject"
    case selectionThreads = "selectionThreads"
    case exportObjID =      "exportObjID"
     */
    case name =             "name"
}
```

}

Comment: So the involved types conforms to `Identifiable`, right? If so I assume the actual type for the `id` property conforms to `Codable`? You probably want something like `var project: Project.ID`

Comment: Hmm.... maybe I see that as a better solution. I've started a process to simply generate UUIDs, which are Codable out of the box, and use them for the encoded objects. Since generally I'd rather let CoreData handle the ObjectIdentifier side of things, it seems like good practice to abstract the whole thing away, and not let any dependencies on the original identifiers get in the way... Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Which part of this question relates to Core Data?

Comment: @TomHarrington : Thank you so much for your thoughtful and constructive inquiry. The answer would seem to be the part where it involves an ObjectIdentifier, pervasive throughout CoreData stores, and part of every single record created by it? Since UUIDs are encoded in a struct, and ObjectIdentifiers are not, it seems like it's at the heart of the question.

Comment: `ObjectIdentifier` is not a Core Data term. You may be thinking of `NSManagedObjectID`, which is, but which is not the same as a Swift `ObjectIdentifier`.